# Delphi - ActionToolBar how to get Submenu property on Action execute event

Tags: delphi

In Delphi on ActionToolBar how to get "Tag" property of Submenu Item on Action->onExecute event.

[image]

So **not Action Tag**, I need TActionClientItem ("Open") tag property on submenu trigger that action OR Main Button (Action2) Tag or even Main Button ("Action2") index (position) on ActionToolBar … all on Submenu Action-> onExecute event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, that is not possible.

Usually the triggering component can be retrieved via the action's `ActionComponent` property, but doesn't work in this case because `TActionClientItem` is not derived from `TComponent`.

Comment: In this case it's `TCustomActionMenuBar.ExecAction` method that is responsible for setting `ActionComponent` to `nil`, because it invokes `FSelectedItem.ActionLink.Execute` with default (`nil`) argument as `ActionComponent`, which is a shame. It could have invoked `Execute` with `Self` as an argument, so it would be possible to access `TCustomActionMenuBar` instance and its `FSelectedItem` of type `TActionClientItem`, although the field is `protected`. This can be fixed by registering custom action popup style, but I find it too desperate for what's required.

Comment: Hi Peter Wolf, thank you for respond. Yes you are totally write as usual :). I'v change design and decide to dynamically create popup for every button. (popup using same actions) and on creation simple setting popup tag…then after on button dropdownMenu onpop event retrieving and storing that tag from popup. Now working as expected. Thanks again. TK